# How to restrict to select multi Select of Files in Open FileDialog?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have some task to select files in VB6 with the control "CommonDialog1".When the project is migrated this control is converted to openfile dialog.When some of the properties are not converted it is showing as commented.
This line was commented

```
'CommonDialog1.Flags = CommonDialog1.Flags Or &H80000  ' Dont ALLOWMULTISELECT
```

I want to know do we have any propery in VB.NET for Open File Dialog Control?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog_members(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make a quick search, or use the help of IntelliSense if you're using Visual Studio.

```
Dim myOpenFile as New OpenFileDialog()
myOpenfile.Multiselect = False
```

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog_members%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)